# Oracle VM installation error

Tags: windows-server-2003, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I'm trying to install Windows server 2003 on Oracle VM which is installed on Windows 7. I've installed Oracle VM for 64 bit and extension pack on Windows 7. I followed the steps to create Windows 2003 and when tried to start this, I got message saying that "No bootable medium found, System halted". I found some thread and it says that I need to have ISO image. 
I've downloaded ISO from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=21700 but still no luck.
Can you please let me know from where I can get it and how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You must install the OVM Server (physical server) then install the OVM Manager on a Linux machine, and then using the OVM Manager to create the VM.
Here's a link to documentation for the following:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35328_01/index.html

Answer (score 0):

As the OVM version is not shared (considering it to be latest one i.e OVM 3.4.1) only Microsoft Windows Server 2003 R2 SP2 is supported. Please see below :

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E64076_01/E64077/html/vmrns-guest-os-x86.html

Apart from it, "No bootable medium found, System halted" simply means that the bootloader is not found. In this case you can check few stuffs like, corrupt ISO image or if the ISO image is properly attached to the Guest VM and making it as primary bootable device.

Please follow below process : 
1. Check if downloaded iso integrity. Reconfirm the same by matching md5 sum.

2. Place the ISO in http/ftp location and import the same to Oracle VM Manager.
3. Attach the ISO to Guest VM and make it primary bootable device.
   http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E64076_01/E64082/html/vmusg-svrpools-vm-create.html (Step 6,7)
4. Start the Guest VM